# Restricting user access to certain features via registry on Windows 8.1 Home Premium

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, user-accounts, group-policy

I need to restrict user access to Control Panel for example. And because its Home Premium version of Windows it doesn't have Group Policy Manager. Im using this list to do those restrictions. First problem is that adding `NoControlPanel` key with value `1` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Policies\Explorer` doesn't really restrict the user from accessing it. and the other problem is that in order to do those restrictions I need to set account type of the user I want to restrict to administrator so it can make registry changes log in to that user and then add entries to the registry. So I'm wondering if there is any other way to do those restrictions? Maybe there is some other software to do it instead of manually adding registry keys?

Comment: Why prevent access to Control Panel? Regular users can't make system-wide changes or changes that are likely to make Windows become unstable... If you don't trust your users then turn the Guest account on...

Comment: Well I'm going to give that PC for my grandpa to use. I'm sure he won't change anything on purpose but because he is hard learner than it comes to computers or mobile phones so I just want to restrict as much features which I know he won't need as I can.

Comment: I'd suggest the Guest account in this instance. He should be able to create/save documents etc. to "Documents", use applications you've installed and browse the Internet if connected. The system will be very restricted but may work better in this instance. Alternatively, use a normal account but turn up the UAC so if he tries to do something accidentally then it'll prompt for your admin password...

Comment: Well I'll do that if there is no other choice to do the restrictions. thanks for your suggestions.